# Error message when creating an email but still goes through

Tags: python-2.7

I have the code below set up to create an email and attach a file then send it. It works like a charm but it always gives me an error on the last file after sending it. Almost as if it is trying to do the last file twice. Later in the code I move all the files in the folder which is what I initially thought the problem was but when I programed the error catching it is somewhere in this segment.

Error example when only one file is in folder - Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\hlooman\Desktop\TestFolder\ProccessedReports\~$TestFile1.xlsx'

```
path ='C:\Users\hlooman\Desktop\TestFolder\ProccessedReports'
extension = '.xlsx'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
        try:
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = os.environ['TEST_EMAIL']
            msg['To'] = os.environ['TEST_EMAIL']
            msg['Subject'] = 'Formated Renewal Report'
            message = 'Attached are the formated reports'
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))          
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "rb") as attachment:
                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                part.set_payload((attachment).read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)          
                msg.attach(part)
                mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
                # identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
                mailserver.ehlo()
                # secure our email with tls encryption
                mailserver.starttls()
                # re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
                mailserver.ehlo()
                mailserver.login(os.environ['TEST_EMAIL'], os.environ['TEST_PASS'])
                mailserver.sendmail(os.environ['TEST_EMAIL'],os.environ['TEST_EMAIL'],msg.as_string())
                mailserver.quit()
        except Exception as error2:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            log.write(str(d) + " Error " + str(error2) + " occured during email creation of " + str(filepath))
            log.write("\n")
            log.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible you had the file open in Excel at the time? I believe (but am not sure) Excel might make lock files which could cause an issue maybe?

Comment: `~$something.xslx` files are temporary/lock excel files. You shoudn't process them; filter them out instead of processing every `.xlsx` file.

Comment: About these files : https://superuser.com/questions/901730/why-do-i-see-filename-hidden-excel-files

Comment: @etene how would I modify the following statement to do that?
if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == extension and filename != '/~/$*':

Comment: I was just writing a more detailed answer that explains how to do that in a Pythonic way :) Just wait a minute, I'm on a train and my connection is lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
path ='C:\Users\hlooman\Desktop\TestFolder\ProccessedReports'
extension = '.xlsx'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
        # process file
```

You should use [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob), which is simpler, more readable and will filter out unwanted files that start with `~`, like this:

```
from glob import glob
path = r'C:\Users\hlooman\Desktop\TestFolder\ProccessedReports'
for filename in glob(path + r'\[!~]*.xslx"):
    # process files
```

The glob pattern matches all filenames in `path` that end with `.xlsx` but don't start with `~`. See the [fnmatch module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html%20fnmatch) for more details on filename pattern matching.

If you have large numbers of files to process, you can use [glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) which does the same thing but returns an iterator instead of a list to save memory.

You'll notice that I used strings prefixed with `r`: these deactivate the special meaning of escape characters like `\`, which can be pretty annoying when dealing with Windows file paths. The double backslashes I used in my former example are another, albeit clumsier, way to deal with this problem.

I can't test it for real because I have neither a Windows machine nor Excel at hand, but that should do the trick. Don't hesitate if something needs clarification.

Comment: So I implemented this and now it is not catching any of the files. Can I ask why you do two backslashes? also what is the function of the square brackets in the str?

Comment: I'm outside on mobile, i'll get back to you later but meanwhile you can look up  backslashes' special meaning in Python and the fnmatch module for the square brackets meaning.